# JavaScript length method always return a one for json object

Tags: javascript

I'm just learning json.  I'm trying to loop through an array, but the length is 1, even though the array has 3 elements. Why am I getting 1 instead of 3? Here is the code:

```
LoadPendingMsg: function()
{
  // Load attachments

  this.serverPendingMsg = { 
    "Attachments" : [
             { LinkNaname:"ted", LinkUrl: "www.ted",
               LinkNaname:"ted", LinkUrl: "www.ted",
               LinkName:"ted", LinkUrl: "www.ted"}
       ],
    "Message" : "Hello sample message"
  };

// size is one, should be 3??????????
size=this.serverPendingMsg.Attachments.length;  
for (i=0; i < size; i++)
```

Comment: You are confusing **Java** with **JavaScript**. They have almost nothing in common except two things: 1) both have "_Java_" in their names, 2) both are programming languages. I corrected the title of your question.

Comment: Hi,thank you for the explaining that I do not have an array, if I wanted to have it as a array so it would be somthing like LinkeName[3] and LinkUrl[3] how would I do it????

Comment: Just follow the answer you have accepted. This is the best approach in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Attachments` property as shown in your question is an array with *one* element, where that element is an object with six properties (well, actually three properties - see my note below). I think you intended to have an array of three similar objects each of which has two properties, like this:

```
this.serverPendingMsg = {
   "Attachments" : [
       { LinkNaname:"ted", LinkUrl: "www.ted"},
       { LinkNaname:"ted", LinkUrl: "www.ted"},
       { LinkName:"ted", LinkUrl: "www.ted"}
    ],
    "Message" : "Hello sample message"
};

size=this.serverPendingMsg.Attachments.length;
alert(size); // 3
```

Note that the way you had it that object has the same property names used several times, which apparently doesn't give an error in some browsers but those properties will be overwriting each other - an object can only have a single property with a particular name. So your actual object only ends up with the three distinct property names.

(Also you've got `LinkNaname` and `LinkName`, but presumably you meant them all to be `LinkName`.)

NOTE: What you have here is *not* a "JSON object", it is a JavaScript object literal - one of several methods that JavaScript provides to create an object. JSON is a *string* representation of data that uses (almost) the same syntax as JavaScript uses for object literals, hence the abbreviation "JSON" for "JavaScript Object Notation". JSON is (mostly) used as a convenient way to serialise data so it can be transmitted as a string, e.g., in web programming the JSON format is frequently used for Ajax responses.

Answer (score 1):

### Why `length` of your `this.serverPendingMsg.Attachments` is `1`

`this.serverPendingMsg.Attachments` is an **Array with only 1 element** that you define as:

```
{
    LinkNaname:"ted",
    LinkUrl: "www.ted",
    LinkNaname:"ted",
    LinkUrl: "www.ted",
    LinkName:"ted",
    LinkUrl: "www.ted"
}
```

This is why this array's `length` is equal to **one**.

### Why your object is not exactly what you have written

One additional thing: you are defining your object in a way that results in the following object:

```
{
    LinkName: "ted",
    LinkNaname: "ted",
    LinkUrl: "www.ted"
}
```

([see for yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/JqxSW/))

Why? Because **names of object's properties must be unique** - if they are not, they are overwritten.